# What is the name of creature drawn above Ask Question?

Tags: support, design

I like the background image used on this site. I want to know the name of creature present above Ask Question button.

Comment: It sort of reminds me of an angel, but it's difficult to tell from the silhouette alone.

Comment: It looks like a [One Winged Angel](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneWingedAngel). Perhaps it is preparing for a big fight?

Comment: Could it be Kerrigan queen of the blades from starcraft?

Comment: Heidi.  Her name is Heidi.

Comment: We should find someone to be her next time we are at a con. Have a contest for best cosplay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have not given her a name... (feel free to write a lore of her!). I originally gave her two wings, but I thought one wing would be more interesting.

Comment: I always thought both wings were folded together -- with just the silhouette, it's hard to be sure at just what angle the angel's wing comes out from.

Comment: Only half a bell was rung. She only got half her wings.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: Was it that half a bell was rung or a whole bell was only half-rung?

Comment: @TangoOversway Actually I think a [quarter bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_bells) was rung twice :)

Answer (score 8):

Somehow, I always thought of her as the **Angel of Death**.

[image: The Angel of Death awaits]

> Hov'ring over blasted ground,
> Waiting for her soldiers firm;
> Hov'ring over roiling seas,
> Waiting for her sailors sweet.
>
> How the Angel stares around,
> Longing for her prey to squirm:
> Every dying soul she sees
> Can be seized in manner meet.
>
> Runes of summons can be found:
> Hieroglyphics will affirm,
> Those who seek to Death appease,
> Questions ask, for her a treat!

Comment: Is this a Rand al'Thor original? It's very good!

Comment: @fez Yep, I thought my answer should be a bit more than a one-liner, so I came up with a poem off the cuff :-) Thanks!